# Error attempting to read form data from HttpContext

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-core, http-status-code-405

I have a dotnet core web project in which I have added this javascript

```
$trigger.on('click', function () {
   const $button = $(this);
   const resortId = $button.data('resortId');
            
   $.post(url, { resortId: resortId }, function (response) {
       etc...
   });
});
```

The id is being passed correctly and is passed to the following controller method

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("wishlist/add")]
public JsonResult Add()
{
    var response= _repository.Add(Request, HttpContext.Session);
    return Json(response);
}
```

Which makes use of this bit of code

```
private static int GetId(HttpRequest request)
{
  var form = request.Form;
  int.TryParse(form["resortId"], out var resortId);
  return resortId;
}
```

This seems to be where the code is failing

```
var form = request.Form; (Line 82)
```

Which to me is pretty innocuous!
This code works perfectly in my local setup, however when it sits on our staging server it doesn't work!

This is my full stack trace

```
------->
Message. "Incorrect Content-Type: "
Inner Exception.
 ""
StackTrace.
 "   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.ReadForm()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpRequest.get_Form()
   at myproject.GetResortId(HttpRequest request) in Repository.cs:line 82
   at Add(HttpRequest request, ISession session) in Repository.cs:line 31
   at myproject.Controllers.Controller.Add() in Controller.cs:line 28
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)"
<-------
```

I have attempted to send the request using the jQuery ajax call instead of post so that I can explicitly state the content type, but this does not fix the issue.

I don't think it's important but there isn't an SSL certificate on this server (I was originally seeing a 405 response and wondered if this was why).

It's a classic "Works on my machine" situation, but I'm not sure how to further debug this.

**Update**

I have now refactored this to make use of a new object

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("wishlist/add")]
public JsonResult Add(WishListAddRequest request)
{
   etc...
}
```

This gets the collection from the session and updates it with the item passed to the controller.

I now get a 405 response from the server on Staging and it works absolutely fine from my local machine.

**Update 2**

This serves as an answer to my particular problem although it isn't especially helpful to anyone else facing the issue.

I refactored the methods into html forms and posted these to the controllers removing the need for the JavaScript.

I did try to add an SSL certificate to the Staging website to rule out any issues there but ran into network-related problems.

I suspect that because the website has redirect rules pushing http requests to https on a server without SSL, my Ajax calls were falling foul of CORS and if I could prove that I would add an answer to the question.

Comment: The Javascript is POSTing a JSON object containing your value. You should leverage how MVC works to read it. Make a class with a single property of `ResortId` and use that class as a parameter in your `Add()` method. That means you now don't need to pass around the `HttpRequest` which is also a code smell.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for the response. I did go back and put this in class and you are quite right passing the request was far from perfect.
The original issue still persists though it works locally, but not in the staging environment. Back to the original 405 error!

Comment: you mentioned that it worked well locally but not in the staging environment, so is there any difference between the environment?

Comment: @TinyWang This is what I suspect, I'm just not sure what it could be. The only difference that I am aware of is that locally it runs under https and on the staging server its vanilla http.

Comment: I think it's better to create a new case with your staging environment information(e.g you are using IIS as the environment and you did xx configurations) so that other contributors  can help you.